# Derivation of piecewise function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Find $m$ and $b$ so that the function
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}\displaystyle mx + b, & \mbox{if } x< 2,\\
 x^2, & \mbox{if } x\geq 2 \end{cases}
$$
is differentiable everywhere.

Hi. I wonder why we cannot solve the following problem as follows:
If $f$ is differentiable everywhere, then it is
continuous everywhere, so  it must be $b = 4 – 2m.$ Also $m = 2x$ at $x=2$ (taking derivative of each of the pieces). Then $m=4$
In other words, in piecewise functions why we need to use limit definition of derivative and why the my above argument is wrong ? Could you help me ?

Comment: Your argument also works.

Comment: In case this is from a homework assignment, I guess it is an issue of rigorousness and conceptual clarity over getting the correct rough/intuitive idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Naturally, if the function is differentiable everywhere, then your choices would be the only option. However, who is to say that the function you define *is actually differentiable*. To prove this, your lecturer wants you to check the limit definition to see that your assumption really works. Otherwise, you are trapped inside a circular argument: "I assume that the function is differentiable, so it is differentiable".

Comment: I get it now. Thanks for your comment

Comment: @Yılmaz - If Matthias H.'s post has answered your question, you should accept it by clicking on the checkmark.